# Gnu Make, phony prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider this Makefile

```
all: a.out

a.out: group_1 group_2
group_1: CXXFLAGS = -Wall
group_2: CXXFLAGS = -Wextra
group_1: a.o b.o
group_2: c.o
```

Although it'll probably work fine, I want to know what is the proper way of writting that, because according to the GNU Make docs, `group_1` and `group_2` must be `.PHONY` targets, since these are no real targets, but just a way of grouping a set of targets with same config.

But, at the same time, `.PHONY` targets should not be used as prerequisites of other targets as recommended by the docs. So I don't know what is the proper way of specifying a dependence structure like that.

The purpose of doing that is, if I'm not wrong, optimization purposes. I want `CXXFLAGS` is evaluated as less as possible, and I assume that a `Makefile` like

```
all: a.out

a.out: a.o b.o c.o
a.o b.o: CXXFLAGS = -Wall
c.o: CXXFLAGS = -Wextra
```

will evaluated `CXXFLAGS` once per prerequisite, while with the previous method, only once per group, so my first `Makefile` should run faster (extrapolate to bigger dependence trees).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this easily with targets.  The problem is that `a.out` will depend on two *files* `group_1` and `group_2`.  These files never exist, so `a.out` will always be considered out of date.

As for the variable expansion question, your assumption is not correct.  Even in your first example `CXXFLAGS` will be evaluated every time any target is going to be built.  It has to be so, because the variable assignment could be something like:

```
group_1: CXXFLAGS = -DNAME='$@'
```

I'm not sure why you feel that the expansion of variables makes a difference in performance, but if they really take a long time (maybe they invoke `shell` or something) and you're sure that the variables don't have any references to the specific target being built and you want to force them to expand one time only, you could do something like:

```
CXXFLAGS_1 := -Wall
CXXFLAGS_2 := -Wextra

GROUP_1 := a.o b.o
GROUP_2 := c.o

a.out: $(GROUP_1) $(GROUP_2)
$(GROUP_1): CXXFLAGS := $(CXXFLAGS_1)
$(GROUP_2): CXXFLAGS := $(CXXFLAGS_2)
```

Comment: Yeah I use that hack on other contexts. The reason is that I'm doing a GNU Make library with a heavy use of templates, to be added to github soon, and I want to reduce template expansion as much as possible. But I've a doubt, in your solution, will `CXXFLAGS` be expanded only when the prerequisite is considered, or will `:=` be applied when the Makefile is being parsed?

Comment: If you use `:=` it will be expanded once when the makefile is read by make.  If you use `=` it will be expanded each time the value of the variable is needed (e.g., each time `$(CXXFLAGS)` appears in an expansion context).